# On using plyr and ldply

Tags: r, plyr

I have a reoccuring problem - I apologize!

Say I want to have the baseball data (from the plyr package) listed according to 'id' and 'year'. There is a difference between creating the list according to either:

```
1. mylist1 <- dlply(baseball, .(id, year), identity)
```

and

```
2. mylist2 <- dlply(baseball, .(id), dlply, .(year), identity)
```

in the way the list is organized, but getting the list back into a data frame is working fine with 'mylist1'.

```
mydf1 <- ldply(mylist1)
```

but not with 'mylist2'

```
mydf2 <- ldply(mylist2)
```

which gives the following error message:

```
Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_label")): Result must be all atomic, or all data frames
```

I am a newbie to R, and this error message doesn't make much sense to me.

I would like to split my own data frame according to method 2, since I need quite a bit of data manipulation. My question is: how can I merge this list into a data frame? Is there an alternative to `do.call(rbind, do.call(rbind,...`?

I am greatful for any help!

Comment: Why do you need to analyse the data in this way?  I don't think I've ever had to do something like this. Maybe it's just because in designing solutions to problems I try to avoid getting data structures that I can't assemble again.  My preferred way of working is to stick to data.frames whenever possible, i.e. use `ddply` by preference.

Comment: You might be right, but I work with hourly accumulated data of a meteorological data. I have a time series for each station, member of an ensemble, date and forecast time, and for each time series I need to get hourly values - not accumulated values. Sisse

Comment: That is possible using `ddply`.  Without knowing your data structure it's bit hard to double guess, but I suspect that combining all of your data into one massive `data.frame` and ensuring you have the right indices should work.  Good luck with your analysis.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @Andrie that this is an odd structure.  But I assume that you have a particular reason for doing it this way.

Since it took two passes with `dlply` to create `mylist2`, it takes two invocations of `ldply` to put it back together.

```
mydf2 <- ldply(mylist2, ldply)
```

This restores `baseball` (modulo ordering)

```
> class(mydf2)
[1] "data.frame"
> all(dim(mydf2) == dim(baseball))
[1] TRUE
```